# Spring Boot - Swagger generate json/yaml file and client code?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, springfox

Have used springfox dependencies in my spring boot application to show up swagger ui. Used annotation like `@SwaggerDefinition` and `@EnableSwagger2`.

But they are not generating any html's or json/yaml or any client code.
So i used plugin found at : https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-example

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ......
</plugin>
```

But they are not helping either, i guess they are scanning for all @Api class in entire package to generate json, but i have none.

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with [kongchen plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin)

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <apiSources>
                <apiSource>
                    <info>
                        <title>Swagger API Specification for Your Project</title>
                        <version>v0.28</version>
                        <description>Swagger API Specification for Your Project</description>
                    </info>
                    <locations>
                        <location>com.yourpackage.api</location>
                        <location>com.yourpackage.api.controllers</location>
                    </locations>
                    <springmvc>true</springmvc>
                    <outputFormats>json,yaml</outputFormats>
                    <swaggerDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated/swagger-api-spec
                    </swaggerDirectory>
                </apiSource>
            </apiSources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This works for me as well, the trick is to use 2 location one with the controller and the one without 